# How to select only the latest date with specific column data condition

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table with several rows data, I need to only select the latest date of each different group model with the column have included 'BUY and 'A/R' except 'CONSIGN' and 'N/A'. For Example: 
I only want to select the last row which catm is equal to 'BUY'/'A/R'.

```
id      partno       model       catm         date
1.      001          TOYOTA       CONSIGN     2010
2.      001          HONDA        CONSIGN     2009
3.      001          HONDA        BUY         2015
4.      001          TESLA        CONSIGN     2018
5.      001          TESLA        CONSIGN     2018


SELECT partno,max(date) as maxdate
FROM [mytable]
WHERE partno='001'
GROUP BY model
ORDER BY maxdate DESC
```

### id      partno       model       catm         date

empty    empty       empty      empty        empty

The above is the expected result of what I want. Because the latest date catm is 'CONSIGN' it will show nothing. But the actual result will show me this..

```
id      partno       model       catm         date
1.      001          HONDA        BUY         2015
```

Comment: The expected result is missing.

Comment: How is it about c#? Can you please tag which DBMS you are using.

Comment: @jarlh the expected result supposes will me nothing. I only want the latest date if it is 'CONSIGN' it will show nothing. Only the latest date is 'BUY' or 'A/R' it will show me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use common table expression and ROW_NUMBER function to do it check this out,
in this i'm ordering the data set by date desc and put a row number against each, so the RN=1 is always latest record, after that in the select you can put any thing in where clause as you wish.

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY partno ORDER BY date DESC) AS RN,*
FROM MY_TABLE
)

SELECT * FROM T WHERE
RN=1 and
catm IN('Buy', 'A/R')
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it can work in my code. Really thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("partno", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("model", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("catm", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"1.", "001", "TOYOTA", "CONSIGN", 2010});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"2.", "001", "HONDA", "CONSIGN", 2009});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"3.", "001", "HONDA", "BUY", 2015});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"4.", "001", "TESLA", "CONSIGN", 2018});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"5.", "001", "TESLA", "CONSIGN", 2018});

            List<DataRow> latest = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Field<int>("date"))
                .Where(x => x.Field<string>("catm") == "BUY" || x.Field<string>("catm") == "A/R")
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(t.date) over (partition by t.model) as max_date
      from mytable t
     ) t
where t.partno = '001' and
      t.catm in ('Buy', 'A/R') and
      t.date = t.max_date;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping sir, but the result also same as the old code I did. I just want the latest date if it is 'CONSIGN' it will show nothing. Only the latest date is 'BUY' or 'A/R' it will show me.